# Sublime Text open open relative to project directoy

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have a command mapped to ahotkey in sublime to open the user directory...

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+u"], "command": "open_dir", "args": {"dir": "$packages/User/"} },
```

How can I have a similar command that opens a directory two levels up from the project directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path variable `$project_path` expands out to the location of the current `sublime-project` file (which is specific to the current window) in the same way that `$packages` expands to the location of the `Packages` folder.

So, the following will open the directory two levels above the location of the current `sublime-project` file:

```json
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+u"],
    "command": "open_dir",
    "args": {"dir": "$project_path/../../"}
},
```

Sometimes people store their `sublime-project` files in locations other than the locations where their project files are actually stored (e.g. to centralize them all in one location or to remove clutter).

In that case, if you want the binding to open two levels above where the contents of the project are, you can use the `$folder` variable, which expands out to the location of the first folder that's open in the project (or window).

```json
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+u"],
    "command": "open_dir",
    "args": {"dir": "$folder/../../"}
},
```